# accessing the individual values in data.frame R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

In this example

```
cars <- c("FORD", "GM")
price  <- list( c(1000, 2000, 3000),  c(2000, 500, 1000))
myDF <- data.frame(cars=cars, price=cbind(price))
```

How can I access the individual values of price, for example, 500:

something like `myDF$price[2][2]`

Thank you very much.

---

*related to this question:* [column with multiple values in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790148/column-with-multiple-values-in-data-frame)

Comment: While not an answer but I suspect you are having a problem with data organization. Consider looking at reshape2 and in general concept of [stacking/unstacking data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data).

Answer (score 2):

Here are three options:

```
> myDF[[2]][[2]][2]
[1] 500
> myDF[[c(2, 2, 2)]]
[1] 500
> myDF$price[[2]][2] ## This is like what you were after...
[1] 500
```

All basically say, get the second column, then get the second vector from the second column, and then get the second item in the vector.

The third option seems to be what you were trying to do, but `[[` is needed in this case, not `[`.

Answer (score 1):

[I cannot comment so I have to give an answer]

A simpler way to do what you are trying is

```
price  <- data.frame(FORD=c(1000, 2000, 3000), GM=c(2000, 500, 1000))
price$GM[2]
```

Comment: thank you for you comment, however I am not sure if this is the best approach because each raw in general has more than two entries (car, colour, price), what you suggest in this case, for example: `F colour 1000, 2000, 3000` - three columns.